# Calculate a sum of non-zero values in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

I have a scenario where I have 5-6 rows in Crystal Report , Columns are of type "Money" , I want to have the count of all the rows which has Column1's value "Non Zero"

Later I use that count to show in Crystal Report in "TextField"

So far I have created a Formula and typed following code

```
numbervar cnt;
cnt = 1;
if {MyReport;1.Cash_deposit} <> 0.00 then
  cnt = cnt +1;
```

Now I am unable to show this value , any body help?

Sample Data:

```
Cash_Deposit
--------------
10.05
 0.00
25.69
 0.00
89.47
```

In this case I want show (3) in my "TextField"

Comment: If the variable should persist data in between the section it should be declared as shared numbervar cnt;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error...You are missing `:`. Change like this.

```
numbervar cnt;
cnt := 1;
if {MyReport;1.Cash_deposit} <> 0.00 then
  cnt := cnt +1;
```

---

**Approach 1:**

Why are you taking this formula instead you can use in below way.

```
if {MyReport;1.Cash_deposit} <> 0.00 then
     {MyReport;1.Cash_deposit};
```

**Approach 2:**

Supress the filed when count is `zero`

on `supress` formula of the section write below code:

```
 if {MyReport;1.Cash_deposit} = 0.00 then
 true
else false
```

Comment: Approach 1 is incomplete--it will merely show non-zero values.  Approach 2 is wrong--suppressing the field's display does NOT remove it from a summarized-field's calculations.

Comment: @craig. Let user comnent to what extent solution is useful

Answer (score 2):

Create a formula:

```
// {@NonZero}
If {MyReport;1.Cash_deposit}<>0 Then
  1
Else
  0
```

Insert a summarized field; select the formula field; change summary to `Count`; select desired location (optionally, you can create a new group in the window).

The formula field does NOT need to be added to the canvas for this approach to work.